# How to whitelist IPs of the stress-inducing machines for stress testing

Tags: google-app-engine, stress-testing, gae-whitelist

We are trying to stress test our app and we believe we are running into problems related to Google DDoS protection.

One machine can generate 44,000 requests a second to a script that does nothing (returns HTTP 200).

Two machines generate 23,000+- each (roughly half).

Is there any way to white-list the IPs of the stress-inducing machines / Disable this protection for testing?

---

Note: The two machines have a different public IP but share a subnet X.X.*.* [X.X is shared]

Comment: Have you tried slowly ramping up the number of requests per second? Google recommends doing stress testing this way: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/load_test

Comment: Also see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dos
From the looks of it, you have to manually setup DOS protection, it's not something GAE does.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert Thanks for the link, I have seen it and we did slowly ramp up to this point. We can't get past the 44k/30secs ratio. Being that app engine should be able to scale when the script does nothing to many more requests-per-sec we assume the bottleneck is along the way on some network-blocking level. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe there's a bottleneck in your code, have you tried setting up AppStats to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert What do you mean AppStats? Is it something in the console? Couldn't find the specific name..

How ever, I think it doesn't make sense that the app-engine can't scale to more than 1000/sec for a script that does nothing. That's why I suspect network blocking.

Thanks for the help, appreciated :)

Comment: AppStats will show you where you have bottlenecks:
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/03/easy-performance-profiling-with.html